Importing framer-motion into react projects throws compile error
I am trying to import framer-motion into a react project but I get this compile error:
Can't import the named export 'removeBoxTransforms' (imported as 'removeBoxTransforms') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)
I can't figure out how to fix this issue. I am using framer-motion 11.3.0, react 18.3.1, and webpack 5.92.1.
I am importing as instructed in the docs - import { motion } from "framer-motion"
I have also tried some older versions of framer-motion and always get this error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
